# discord-py-slash-command import problems, cant use discord_slash

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have tried using the command line to run the import, I have reinstalled python, I've checked my interpreter, I have spent hours of searching, and nothing works. I have tried using `pip install -U discord-py-interactions` and `pip install -U discord-py-slash-command` but neither of them have worked. It just keeps saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord_slash'`. Does anyone have any idea what's going on? Thanks for any help.

Comment: How are you managing your python virtual environments? You may want to check `which python` and `which pip` to make sure you're installing into the instance of python you expect. Generally, `python -m pip install ...` is preferred to the naked `pip install ...` for this reason.

Otherwise, please provide more detail about your environment and what you have tried

Comment: @tconbeer If I understand correctly, I manage my environements with vscode. [image](https://i.imgur.com/XryUbgj.png). As you can see, I only have one python version, so I do not believe this is the problem.

Comment: Do `mlocate discord-py-slash-command` or something similar to find the location where it's installed. Check to see if that's on your `sys.path` or not.

Comment: It says ``'mlocate' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``

Answer (score 1):

check your discord version.  If it's less than 2.0.0 then you might need to import an older discord-py-slash-commands.  These are the versions that worked for me:

```py
    discord==1.7.3
    discord-py-slash-command==2.0.0
    discord.py==1.7.3
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with pip install discord-py-slash-command